# Converting JSON file to CSV file

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to convert a JSON file into a CSV file. My code is down below. However, I keep getting this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\PythonParse.py", line 42, in <module>
    writer.writerow(data)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\...\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 38409-38412: character maps to <undefined>
```

```py
import json
import gzip
import csv

outfile = open("VideoGamesMeta.csv","w")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

data = []

items = []
names = []

checkItems = False;
checkUsers = False;

numItems = []
numUsers = []

for line in open("meta_Video_Games.json","r",encoding="utf-8"):
    results = (json.loads(line))
    if 'title' in results:
        if 'asin' in results:
            name = results['title']
            item = results['asin']
            data = [item,name]
            writer.writerow(data)
            items.append(item)
            names.append(name)
```

Comment: Most likely you need to specify an `encoding` when you open your `outfile`.

Comment: You can use `sys.getdefaultencoding()` to see how that output file was opened.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I see that I specified the encoding for the JSON file but not for the output file.